# How to map Json to Proto using Jackson Mixin?

Tags: java, json, jackson, protocol-buffers, jackson-databind

We are working in an backend application in which we use `Protobuffers` as model/pojo files.
We have to call an `API` which returns a response as a `JSON`.

I am looking for a solution to map `JSON` files directly to proto. java files.
As an example, we have Example proto in our project:

```
message Example{
 string id                    = 1;
 string another_id            = 2;
 int32 code                   = 3;
 string name                 = 4;
}
```

Now we need to call an `API` which returns response in `JSON`:

```
{
   "json_id":"3",
   "json_another_id":"43",
   "code":34,
   "json_name":"Yeyproto"
}
```

Now, I want to map the response(which is in json) directly with Proto.
please let me know how to do this. Please note since Example.java is an auto generated java file I cannot make any changes in this class. Also, please note the fields of json and proto are different.

Here's what I have tried.
I tried to use Jackson Mixin and keep the mapping information in the mixin class but it didnt work and throw some weird FieldDiscriptor error.

```
public abstract class UserMixin { 
    @JsonProperty("json_id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("json_another_id")
    String another_id;

    @JsonProperty("code")
    int code;

    @JsonProperty("json_name")
    String name;
}
```

and example usage:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixIn(Example.class, ExampleMixin.class);
Position usr = objectMapper.readerFor(Example.class).readValue(json);
System.out.println(json);
```

Exception:

> om.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class
>   com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FieldDescriptor]

Please, help me find a good solution to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes generated by `protoc` compiler are not simple `POJO`. They contain many different methods and types we need to "filter out" to make `Jackson` work.

### Fixed `MixIn` class

Indeed there is a simpler solution than custom deserialiser. You need to ignore `Map<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> getAllFields()` method and improve field names by adding underscore: `_`.

Example:

```
import com.celoxity.protobuf.ExampleOuterClass.Example;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.google.protobuf.Descriptors;
import com.google.protobuf.Timestamp;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProtobufApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .addMixIn(Example.class, ExampleMixin.class)
                .addMixIn(Timestamp.class, TimestampMixin.class)
                .build();

        String json = "{" +
                "\"json_id\":\"3\"," +
                "\"json_another_id\":\"43\"," +
                "\"code\":34," +
                "\"json_name\":\"Yeyproto\"," +
                "\"currTime\":{\"seconds\":1575909372,\"nanos\":35000000}" +
            "}";
        Example deserialised = mapper.readValue(json, Example.class);

        System.out.println(deserialised);
        Timestamp currTime = deserialised.getCurrTime();
        System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(currTime.getSeconds(), currTime.getNanos()));
    }
}

abstract class ExampleMixin extends ProtoBufIgnoredMethods {

    @JsonProperty("json_id")
    String id_;

    @JsonProperty("json_another_id")
    String anotherId_;

    @JsonProperty("code")
    int code_;

    @JsonProperty("json_name")
    String name_;

    @JsonProperty("currTime")
    Timestamp currTime_;
}

abstract class TimestampMixin extends ProtoBufIgnoredMethods {
    @JsonProperty("seconds")
    String seconds_;

    @JsonProperty("nanos")
    String nanos_;
}

abstract class ProtoBufIgnoredMethods {
    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract Map<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> getAllFields();
}
```

Above code prints:

```
id: "3"
another_id: "43"
code: 34
name: "Yeyproto"
currTime {
  seconds: 1575909372
  nanos: 35000000
}

2019-12-09T16:36:12.035Z
```

### Custom deserialiser + `com.hubspot` library

In that case, the <del>simplest solution</del> is to write set of deserialisers and serialisers for all `com.google.protobuf.*` types are compiled into `POJO`. Luckily, there is already implemented module which handles them: [jackson-datatype-protobuf](https://github.com/HubSpot/jackson-datatype-protobuf).

Example usage in your case could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.hubspot.jackson.datatype.protobuf.ProtobufModule;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProtobufApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule pojosModule = new SimpleModule();
        pojosModule.addDeserializer(Example.class, new ExampleJsonDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .addModule(new ProtobufModule())
                .addModule(pojosModule)
                .build();

        String json = "{\"json_id\":\"3\",\"json_another_id\":\"43\",\"code\":34,\"json_name\":\"Yeyproto\"}";
        Example deserialised = mapper.readValue(json, Example.class);
        System.out.println(deserialised);
    }
}

class ExampleJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Example> {
    @Override
    public Example deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode root = p.readValueAsTree();
        return Example.newBuilder()
                .setId(root.get("json_id").asText())
                .setAnotherId(root.get("json_another_id").asText())
                .setName(root.get("json_name").asText())
                .setCode(root.get("json_id").asInt())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Example code prints:

```
id: "3"
another_id: "43"
code: 3
name: "Yeyproto"
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hubspot.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11-jackson2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the response. But you basically calling setters and getters to create Example.java 

 Example.newBuilder()
                .setId(root.get("json_id").asText())
                .setAnotherId(root.get("json_another_id").asText())
                .setName(root.get("json_name").asText())
                .setCode(root.get("json_id").asInt())
                .build()

I am looking for the solution in which we can have a mapping externally. And we dont have to explicitly call getters and setters

Comment: @AvinashKharche, what do you mean by "having a mapping externally"? In your example, you use MixIn class. Could you explain how best solution would look like? Of course, you can replace names before converting to `Example` and then only `ProtobufModule` module will be enough.

Comment: 1. "having a mapping externally" - I mean some other class or file should have mapping definition between json and proto. 
something like this 
json_id -> id
In my example, I am using a abstract mixin class, the advantage of using this is that if we receive new mapping/attribute then we don't need to change any code, but only the mapping file

2. How to change the name of the key's of the json is exactly the issue. 
Converting json to proto if the key matches is easy one can also use JsonFormatter

Comment: @AvinashKharche, using `MixIn` feature was a right way. It just needed some improvements. Take a look on updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @MichalZiober, this works fine with Mixin. I believe Mixin is a great solution. What do you think?

Comment: @AvinashKharche, Definitely! It solves a lot of problems with third-party libraries.

Comment: Hi, it works fine except when we use Timstamp by google
com.google.protobuf.Timestamp;
if anyof the field in Mixin class has this datatype then it throws same issue 
om.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FieldDescriptor]

Do you have any idea how to fix this, please share.

Comment: @AvinashKharche, for all `com.google.protobuf.*` complex types you can create very similar `MixIn` class. Please, take a look on updated answer.

Comment: I am trying to send "currTime":"2019-08-06T04:00:00Z" in the json. But its not working with such input? please let me know if you are aware of the solution.I am getting this issue Cannot construct instance of `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('0.0')

Comment: Also, we expecting to store date in timestamp. So json response will send us date and we will map this date into Timestamp

Comment: @AvinashKharche, please create another question with this problem.

Comment: Hi @MichalZiober
please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287181/how-to-enable-google-protobuf-timestamp-mapping-from-json-to-proto-in-jackson-mi

Answer (score 0):

This is another example of deserializing Json to Proto using `protobuf-java-util` library:

```
        File file = new File("src/test/resources/ACDSResponse.json");
        Reader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        Acds.GetLocalizedAttributesBatchResponse.Builder acdsResponseBuilder = Acds.GetLocalizedAttributesBatchResponse.newBuilder();
        JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(bufferedReader, acdsResponseBuilder);``
```