# How arbitrary JSON string can be deserialized to java POJO?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Lets say we have simple json string `json = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}` and java class

```
class Foo {
private String field1;
private Integer field2;
//setter & getter
}
```

Moreover we don't want to change the `Foo` class. Note that json keys don't match with Foo's fields name.
Is there simple way we can deserilize json string to `Foo` class with Jackson or any other library?

Comment: Write a [**custom deserializer**](https://www.google.com/search?q=jackson+custom+deserializer).

Comment: You may want to implement one of these http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DeserializationProblemHandler.html

Comment: You can use `MixIn` or implement custom deserialiser. See: [Dynamic addition of fasterxml Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290915/dynamic-addition-of-fasterxml-annotation), [How to map Json to Proto using Jackson Mixin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157263/how-to-map-json-to-proto-using-jackson-mixin), [Jackson conditional @JsonUnwrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425419/jackson-conditional-jsonunwrapped)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following json libraries and build a custom deserializer as shown below.

jackson-annotations-2.10.4, 
jackson-core-2.10.4, 
jackson.databind-2.10.4

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FooDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Foo> {


    public static void main (String [] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        String json = "{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":100}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Foo.class, new FooDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);

        System.out.println(foo);
    }


    public FooDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public FooDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctx)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String field1 = node.get("key1").asText();
        int field2 = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("key2")).numberValue();

        return new Foo(field1,field2);
    }
}
```