# SpringMVC global setting for ignoring unknown properties during deserialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, deserialization

Spring Boot sets "spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false" by default.  I have a library that works fine in Spring Boot, but when used in an existing SpringMVC app it throws "Unrecognized field, not marked as ignorable".  Is there some comparable global setting for SpringMVC I can set in the config or otherwise?

edit: spring webmvc version 3.2.15.RELEASE

Comment: Which SpringMVC version is that?

Comment: Spring version 3.2.15.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the mapped classes with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

or create add the following configuration to the ObjectMapper as follows:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: yes, but I don't have access to the source

Answer (score 1):

You can follow two method that I have mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69032716/16709163) answer. If I'm not wrong either one will work for you. (But method 1 won't work if your clinet class does not have a no-arg default constructor)

Comment: Unfortunately Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder isn't in spring 3.2.15; not until 4.1.1 I think.

Comment: not yet, I tried your good idea of the custom de-serializer, but it doesn't work because I'm stuck with spring 3.2.15 for now.  I will see if there is similar approach with that version tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: @bob if you can share your code, it will be helpful

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any code to share. I added a library that normally runs in spring boot to my already running springmvc app and it throws that exception. I was hoping there was some setting I could do to make it ignore unknown fields.