# How to customize Protobuf message json transformation

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuffer UUID message represented by two ints

```
message ApiUUID {
  uint64 most = 1;
  uint64 least = 2;
}
```

which is then used in all other messages

```
message Data {
  ApiUUID id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  ..
}
```

This works fine when serializing to binary files, its much smaller and faster to read then the variant where UUID is a string.

But when I try to convert it to json using the built in

```
JsonFormat.Printer printer = JsonFormat.printer().omittingInsignificantWhitespace();
        String json = printer.print(planningData);
```

the ID is printed like

```
{"id":{"most":"8024373369477287721","least":"13459779257196482731"}
```

Is there an option to transform the ApiUUID to JSON as a UUID string, rather then an object? So convert the most + least into UUID and print it as string.

Using Java.

Comment: Side-note: Your UUID components should most likely be `fixed64`. A variable-length-encoded (uint64) int has a small perf overhead and is usually only suitable for small-ish values. For big values that would normally san 4 bytes anyway, it will also be bigger and likely occupy 5 bytes. A fixed64 simply writes the inderlying `long`.

Comment: FYI I looked for a way to add (Jackson) annotations to the generated code so that you could encode the values using Jackson, but apparently out of the box this is not possible: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4635. But of course you could use a Jackson Mixin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157263/how-to-map-json-to-proto-using-jackson-mixin, and specifically write a de/serializer for your UUID type while _maybe_ not having to write Jackson code for every type...? Not sure, have fun!